# Find the reason for FTP 500 error?

Tags: ftp, 500-error

How do I find the exact reason for the FTP 500 error - System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized

This happened while doing FTP transfers with a C# code (code might not be necessary). All files below 300KB are transferred without error. But only the 320KB one is transferred with error. How do I find out the cause ?

Comment: Stack Overflow might be a better site for this question.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard - Not sure. No reponses there either.

Comment: Do yuu have administrative access to the remote server?

Comment: You've asked this same question on Server fault. Please don't cross-post. Pick the best Stack Exchange site and ask your question there; If you feel you picked the wrong site flag your question & request migration.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general error message.

Pls take a look at the event log on server to view detailed error message.

Make sure the Url you specified in code is correct.

Pls go through following url for more details and fix,

http://miserrors.blogspot.in/2010/10/systemnetwebexception-remote-server.html

Comment: No. I don't think that is applicable here. I can transfer some files in my for loop without problems.